# Where to put Files for Mono Application in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, mono, filesystems

I am writing a C# application (in Visual Studio on Windows) that will be run as a mono application on Unix (Raspbian aka Debian).  I am a Unix noob, and though I have read (well, skimmed) the [Linux Foundation Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) I am still not completely clear on where I should put the files my application will need.  I have:

1. The compiled C# application (app.exe).  I thought I would put this in **/usr/bin**, except that the application is not run directly (it is invoked by "mono app.exe"), so maybe **/usr/libexec** is a better location?
2. Configuration files (there may be more than one) (app.1.conf, app.2.conf, etc.).  If they are not user specific, I would think **/etc/app** (a directory, not a file) would be a good place for these.  How about if they are user specific?  **/home/**?
3. Log file (app.log).  Seems that **/var/log** is the right place for this.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at an already established Mono app for reference. For example let's take MonoDevelop:

1. The exe file goes to /usr/lib/{appnameinlowercase}/bin/ , but they place a launcher script in /usr/bin, named *{appnameinlowercase}*, for easy launch from the command line (this script just calls `exec mono YourAppName.exe`).
2. In .NET the config files need to be in the same directory as the executable file, so you could place them in /usr/lib/{appnameinlowercase}/bin, then later for convenience, put symlinks to them from /etc/{appnameinlowercase}/.
3. Correct, /var/log/{appnameinlowercase}/ should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That's just what I needed.